# How to retrieve cookies in servlet (display everything)

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

```
String userNmae = req.getParameter("userName");
Cookie ck = new Cookie("hello", vall);
res.addCookie(ck);
```

//lets suppose, I've stored 5 different users name or integer in cookie.

```
Cookie [] cookies = req.getCookies();
            String name;
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                 name = cookie.getValue();
                req.setAttribute("vav", name);
                req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(req, res);
              }
```

//Now I would like to retrieve all the values and display on jsp page. How would I do that..

```
${vav}
```

jsp file..
Thank you all in advance..

Comment: are you using spring? you should add var to your model before returning the jsp. Something like model.put("vav", req.getAttribute("vav")) or in jsp <%= request.getAttribute("vav") %>

Comment: I am trying to send a list of  user input; history of number.. when I do the current way above, I only get one number print out on jsp... just got stuck on printing everything from the cookie..

Comment: Your data seems sensitive and should be stored in the session rather than in the cookie. Cookies are used for keeping user preferences like "Remember password" and can be "hacked" pretty easily. Do you have some constraints to use the session instead of the cookie?

Comment: No... I could do either way; cookie or HttpSession. I tried to solve this problem with HttpSession first. I had a same problem... I am just having hard time with printing everything either way..

Comment: Could you post more of your code : controller methods, jsp, project dependencies? Using session is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I meant to edit your initial question with more details.

Comment: Could you please give a example if possible... for example - Lets make a user to enter two numbers then submit and send it to java(servlet). And also we can provide them with history button so they can request the history list.. If user clicks on history button, print all the previous numbers to them.. then I will figure it out what I was doing wrong.. I hope that is not too much to ask for.. (my code is pretty long...) I just wanted to know the concept..on how to print history to users.. Thank you Adina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example to demonstrate session usage:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    private static final String USER_HISTORY = UserController.class.getName() + "_USER_HISTORY";

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public User getUserModelAttribute() {
        return new User();
    }

    @GetMapping("/history")
    public String getHistoryView(HttpSession httpSession, Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("userHistory", getUserHistory(httpSession));
        return "index";
    }

    private List<User> getUserHistory(HttpSession httpSession) {
        // check if session exists
        Object history = httpSession.getAttribute(USER_HISTORY);
        if (history != null && history instanceof List) {
            return (List<User>) history;
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @PostMapping("/user")
    public String saveUser(HttpSession httpSession, @ModelAttribute User user) {
        List<User> history = getUserHistory(httpSession);
        history.add(user);
        httpSession.setAttribute(USER_HISTORY, history);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

and the jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form:form method="POST" action="/user" modelAttribute="user">
         <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="firstName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="lastName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>

    <a href="/history">See Your History</a>

    <c:if test="${not empty userHistory}">
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${userHistory}">
            ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're awesome.. Thank you.. This is really helpful... Thank you Thank you..Thank you.. so much... Now I can fix my problem... Thank you again... Adina..

Comment: You are welcome, please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring, I suppose you have a controller class for the view you want to display the information on. Just add the stored information to the given model, which you can then retrieve using the expression language.

Something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String login(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request){
   // retrieve all data from cookies and save it somewhere in a List/Map
   model.addAttribute(cookieData);
   return "login";
}
```

Then in JSP loop over the map using JSTL and EL and display what you need:

```
<c:forEach items="${cookieData}" var="cookie">
  <p>${cookieData.userName}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

Hopefully this gives you some insight.

EDIT: make sure to import JSTL in the JSP page before attempting the foreach loop.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

I also agree that sensitive data should never be stored in cookies as they are easily accessible.